# "Cannot find module" error on js file import

Tags: node.js

I get this error on an app.js file that's being run with node. I'm trying to import another file this way (trying to use require gives another error):

```
import { sequelize } from './db'
```

The db.js file looks like this:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize' 

// Estabelecendo conexao do banco de dados
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'adminos',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'admin',
    dialect: 'postgres'
})

export default sequelize
```

Both are in the same directory. What could be causing this?

Error log:

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'E:\CANAL NAO MEXA\Projetos\AdminOs Demo\adminos-demo\server\src\db' imported from E:\CANAL NAO MEXA\Projetos\AdminOs Demo\adminos-demo\server\src\app.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:231:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:850:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1058:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:164:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:419:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove brackets as you have exported as default

`import sequelize from './db'`

Comment: Removing the brackets still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

you have to import like this `import sequelize from './db';`

Comment: if I import like that it still get's me the same error

Comment: Try below :

1.Change import sequelize from './db' to import sequelize from './db.js'(if this not working go for 2nd)
2.Next , If you are using ES Modules, add "type": "module" in package.json 

-Restart the server

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, we refer each file to a module, so your db.js file is a module in which you wrote some code for database connection.

To import and export modules in ES6 we have two ways.

**1. Default export**

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize({});

export default sequelize;
```

When we do a default export then we do not use the curly braces to import the modules.

Import the default export.

```js
import sequelize from './db';
```

**2. Named export**

```js
export const dbName = 'MongoDB';
export const dbPassword = '12345xxxx';
```

Now to import the named exports we use object destructuring.

```js
import { dbName, dbPassword } from './db';
```

To learn more about JavaScript modules you can visit the W3School.
[W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_modules.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Nodejs. Please try this

`const { sequelize } = require('./db.js');`

```
const { Sequelize } =  require('sequelize'); 

// Estabelecendo conexao do banco de dados
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'adminos',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'admin',
    dialect: 'postgres'
})
module.exports = sequelize;
```